# How do I assemble filtered graphs in Jung Java API

Tags: java, jung

I'm trying to use the `Jung API (v2)` to analyse a graph in Java.

I've applied an `EdgePredicateFilter`, which according to the docs returns an unassembled graph.

Apparently I'm now meant to assemble the graph, which should remove all the nodes without edges, using a call to an `assemble()` method, but I'm not sure where to find it. If I try and import `edu.uci.ics.jung.filters.UnassembledGraph` I get an error saying there's no such class.

How do I assemble the filtered subgraph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking at the docs for v1, not v2:
http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/filters/EdgePredicateFilter.html
In v2, EdgePredicateFilter.transform() returns a Graph, plain and simple.

If you want to remove the nodes without edges after your edge predicate filter has finished, you can do that as a separate VertexPredicateFilter pass.

Comment: Thanks. Is that the same for KNeighborhoodFilter? The docs say "Constructs an unassembled graph containing the k-neighborhood around the root node(s)". Can I just ignore that and treat it as a regular Graph? Also, if I give a DirectedGraph to the transform method, can I expect a DirectedGraph back?

Comment: (1) v2 no longer has the concept of an UnassembledGraph; again, you're looking at the v1 docs. (2) No, as the signature for transform() specifies, it returns a Graph, although you can cast it to a DirectedGraph.

Comment: Sorry, but I am looking at the v2 docs, and for the transform method of the KNeighborhoodFilter class it states that an unassembled graph is constructed. From what you're saying though, it seems like that's incorrect, and the returned graph will be an instance of whatever concrete graph type was actually passed to the filter.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that; you're correct, the docs of that method are out of date (presumably didn't get updated when we changed it to use Transformer).  Yes, the returned graph will be an instance of whatever concrete type was passed in.